# Internet does not work if Proxy is enabled for wifi on Android device

Tags: android, proxy, fiddler

I'm trying to use the Fiddler to record the network traffic from my phone. I have setup fiddler on my laptop, enabled remote computers to connect.

I had to edit the wifi connection details on my Phone to include my laptop IP and port on which Fiddler is running. But when I do that, on phone wifi shows "Limited Connectivity" and does not connect to the internet.

How can I ensure that I have internet running with proxy enabled?
Settings on phone related to proxy - 
Proxy: Manual
Hostname:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
Port: 8888 (same as in Fiddler)
Ip Settings: DHCP
Privacy: Use randomized MAC

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What Android version has the used device? How have you added the Fiddler root certificate to the device?Note: Just installing it as user certificate has no effect since Android 6.

Comment: @Robert Android Version is 10. there was a fiddler root certificate installed by default named as DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, and I added another by visiting http://ipv4.fiddler:8888. I tried even after removing the second one but it still doesn't work. Do you recommend removing the first one as well?

Comment: As I said those user installed certificates are useless it does not matter if you install them or delete them. Only using app modification (via app repackaging or dynamically via Frida) or root permission and install the Fiddler-root-CA cert as system certificate you will be able to intercept traffic.

Comment: But the issue I'm facing is the internet getting away from the phone as soon as proxy is enabled on Mobile phone. Application-level changes are done and root certificate is trusted and installed on my machine/laptop.

Comment: That you have installed the Fiddle-Root-CA cert on your laptop is nice but has no effect an Android. I don't have experience with Android 10 but may be Google also uses an HTTPS url for connectivity check. If this is the case you have to install the Fiddler Root-ca certificate on Android as system certificate - which requires root permissions.